# How to find a resource that is part of the mainwindow

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, coding-style, resources

I have a style resource in my main window xaml file. I am creating a separate class and I am trying to set the style like this:

```
Style = (Style)Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("DesignerItemStyle");
```

but it is not finding it, I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If are referring to the style of an *instantiated* class, you should put it inside a function for this to work. I assume, that you are trying apply the style to a current UI element, i.e

```
Style = (Style)Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("DesignerItemStyle");
```

or

```
this.Style = (Style)Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("DesignerItemStyle");
```

At any other place, it would throw an error as it would refer to the generic **Style** class itself & not an instance of the class. Try moving it into the class constructor for example.

---

Usually, when a style is used over multiple classes, you may rather turn it into an application Resource.
(Use App.xaml) & access it as in the following example:

```
Style myStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["myStyleName"];

contructor() {

     this.Style = mystyle;

     }
```